# Pagination (block) missing

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, pagination

Most of the times I find a solution here, but in this case it's a little more complicated. I followed the instructions given in several posts, but none of them worked.

The pagination block should be there if I take a look inside the `catalog.xml` file:

```
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
```

Maybe this could be something worth telling: When I check the template hints, there's no such block. The template is a customized version of the RWD theme.

this is the url: https://www.kweekotheek.nl/kweeklampen/led.html

Answer (score 3):

The toolbar is being loaded, it just has a CSS style set to display: none;

```
.toolbar, .pager {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To show toolbar please add below css

```
.toolbar, .pager {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: don't add the duplicate answer..